# How to I use PDF and Text file from External storage in android 13 flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How to I use PDF and Text file from External storage in android 13 flutter

Now android was change storage permission to 3 spreate permissions

Images and photos: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
Videos: READ_MEDIA_VIDEO Audio
Audio files: READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

I was try to store PDF file and Text file
How can I do it..?

I need to use Files permission (PDF,Text and files)

Comment: Those three are only for reading media files of other apps. You dont need them if your app wants to  save files.

Comment: Your post further is unclear as first you talk about using files and later about storing files. Come to the point please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.